# Html sprite showing full height

Tags: html

I have a div which I have a plus icon to expand the view. When the user hovers overs the icon moves to the green version.

I am now adding a extra line of text but now the full icon gets shown. I am not sure how to set the height to only allow the fist part of the icon to be show.

```
<div class="span-5 roomtitle">
   <a href="#">Classic Double Room</a>
   <br>Sleeps: 2
</div>
```

css:

```
.roomtitle {
            background: url("../images/icons/icon_add.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
            color: #990000;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding-left: 25px;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sprite in the link instead of the div:

```
.roomtitle { 
    color: #990000; 
    line-height: 14px; 
}
.roomtitle > a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    background: url("../images/icons/icon_add.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; 
    padding-left: 25px; 
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/U285K/

Comment: This will be the same as what he had because the a tag will take up 100% of the height of the div.

Comment: @locrizak - How would the link possible take up 100% of the height of the div?  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/U285K/

Comment: sorry I didn't see the height. Styling the second line is still a little tickier

Comment: @locrizak - even without the height, the link still would not fill the container.  It is an inline element.  Height is needed to make the link larger to accomodate the image, not smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1) you can change the sprite so that there is a gap inbetween each image (not very good)

2) add a span within the `.roomtitle` div and add the sprite to that. (this is the approch I will usually take)

```
.roomtitle{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url("../images/icons/icon_add.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```